# Parsing JSON in java from class to main

Tags: java, json

I have a main class and a normal java class. One is the one that will parse everything from the URL the other will print it all out.
One example I have is it's all in main and in a private static void class, but when I want to put this into a separate class I get an error in either the main or parse class depending on what I define the constructer.

This is the main class

```
URL url = new URL("https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/master?type=RANKED_FLEX_SR&api_key=RGAPI-fdf965a6-41b8-4fac-831a-f4aaeb133659");

    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(in);

    myJsonParser json = new myJsonParser(reader.readObject());
```

This is the other class. If I change public void to private void I can't get it outside of the class.

```
public void myJsonParser(JsonObject object)
{
    Set<String> fields = object.keySet();
            for( String st : fields){

                //Array
                JsonArray ja = null;
                //Object
                JsonObject jo = null;
                //String
                JsonValue jv = null;

                try{
                    ja = object.getJsonArray(st);
                }catch( ClassCastException ex1){
                    try{
                        jo = object.getJsonObject(st);
 ``                   }catch( ClassCastException ex2){
                        try{
                            jv = object.get(st);
                        }catch( ClassCastException ex3){
                            System.out.println("EXCEPTION");
                        }
                }
                }

                if(ja != null){
                    //System.out.println(st + " is a Array " + ja.toString());
                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.size(); i++) {
                        //Returns JSON objects
                        JsonObject object2 = ja.getJsonObject(i);
                        myJsonParser(object2);

                    }
                }else if(jo != null){
                    System.out.println(st + " is a Object " + jo.toString());


                }else if( jv != null){
                    System.out.println(st + " is a String " + jv.toString());
                }

            }                
}
```

Is there a way for me to get access to the class both inside and outside? I'm trying to get this to work then transfer it to JSPs or even a way to have so I don't have to use a main class since I'm going to be bringing it over to JSPs anyway.

EDIT: I also need to use return types but when I try doing a return I also get an error

Comment: You should make the method return something and it needs to be public if you want to use it outside the class. Printing is not the same as returning, but your question isn't really clear what you want

Comment: You also need to learn the difference between a class, a method, and a constructor.

Comment: myJsonParser json = new myJsonParser(reader.readObject()); This in the main class gives me an error telling me there is no arguments in the constructor. @JBNizet You're right yeah